# Converting date range to datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a bunch of time ranges that are formatted like 'Mar 24, 2019 12:45 AM - Apr 25, 2019 12:44 AM'.

I am wondering how I can convert each of these time ranges into a list of the start and end dates where the start and end dates are of the datetime64[ns] format?

I tried to use datetime.datetime and parse through these time ranges to convert each range to start and end times but I cannot figure out the proper way to do this since I have three main obstacles - first the month is formatted as 3 letters, second the time is not in 24 hour format, third there is a time range denoted by the '-' that I think the only eway to deal with is separating this string into two based on when the '-' occurs?

Comment: Those are strings, not time or date ranges. Dates in all programming languages are binary values, they have no format. You need to parse those strings into dates then use [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to generate a range of dates.

Comment: To parse the date literals (strings) you first need to split on `-`, then use `strptime` with the correct format, eg `"%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p"`

Comment: what did you try? what did not work? often, coming up with a [mre] brings you already one step closer to a solution...

Comment: @FObersteiner people that live in countries that use 24-hour clock may not know  that AM/PM can be parsed or where to start. *I* thought that everyone used AM/PM and 24-hour clocks were the exception until a few years ago

Answer (score -1):

Dates are binary values, they have no formats. Formats are used when converting dates to strings for display, or parsing date literals (strings) into date-typed values.

You can use [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to generate a range between two dates.

To parse the string `Mar 24, 2019 12:45 AM` you can use [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) with the format `%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p`:

```
the_input='Mar 24, 2019 12:45 AM - Apr 25, 2019 12:44 AM'
the_parts=the_input.split(' - ')
the_dates=[datetime.strptime(p,"%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p") for p in the_parts]
the_range=pd.date_range(the_dates[0],the_dates[1])
```

This produces a date range with a frequency of 1 day by default

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-24 00:45:00', '2019-03-25 00:45:00',
               '2019-03-26 00:45:00', '2019-03-27 00:45:00',
               '2019-03-28 00:45:00', '2019-03-29 00:45:00',
               '2019-03-30 00:45:00', '2019-03-31 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-01 00:45:00', '2019-04-02 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-03 00:45:00', '2019-04-04 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-05 00:45:00', '2019-04-06 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-07 00:45:00', '2019-04-08 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-09 00:45:00', '2019-04-10 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-11 00:45:00', '2019-04-12 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-13 00:45:00', '2019-04-14 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-15 00:45:00', '2019-04-16 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-17 00:45:00', '2019-04-18 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-19 00:45:00', '2019-04-20 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-21 00:45:00', '2019-04-22 00:45:00',
               '2019-04-23 00:45:00', '2019-04-24 00:45:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```